# For loop variable used in templatetag?

Tags: django, templatetags

Trying to solve a problem with templatetags.

I have two templatetags:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('directory/_alphabet.html')
def alphabet_list(names):
    """ Return a list of letters that last names start with. """
    return { 'letters': [name.last_name[0] for name in names] }

class NameNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, letter, var_name):
        self.letter = letter
        self.var_name = var_name

    def render(self, context):
        context[self.var_name] = Person.objects.get_active().filter(
            last_name__istartswith=self.letter)
        return ''

@register.tag
def get_names(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires arguments" % \
                token.contents.split()[0]
    m = re.search(r'for (.*?) as (\w+)', arg)
    if not m:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag had invalid arguments" % \
              tag_name
    letter, var_name = m.groups()
    return NameNode(letter, var_name)
```

And I want to use them like so:

```
{% for letter in letters %}
<h2>{{ letter }}</h2>
{% get_names for letter as names %}
<ul>
    {% for name in names %}
    <li>{{ name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But 'letter' gets sent as the word 'letter' and not as whatever letter the variable should contain. Is there a way around this or something I'm missing (or, better yet, a package that already does this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the string `"letter"` because this is what the template parser read from your template source. If you want to access the value of this variable, you have to mark it as a template variable in `NameNode.__init__` and *resolve* it using the context in `render`.

As follow:

```
class NameNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, letter, var_name):
        self.letter = template.Variable(letter)
        self.var_name = var_name

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            context[self.var_name] = Person.objects.get_active().filter(
                last_name__istartswith=self.letter.resolve(context))
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            pass
        return ''
```

It's explained in the docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag).